# What is the preferred way of loading Lottie files from internal folder in a .NET MAUI app?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, maui, skiasharp

I am in process to migrate Xamarin Forms project to MAUI. I am stuck with SkiaSharp lottieFiles json load issue.

In my app, i download json lottiefile at runtime and save in a app's internal folder. in xamarin, CODE side app can load downloaded file from given path. but in MAUI it is not working from CODE side folder given path.

From last 3 days i tried all kind of path combintation and also tried to search online solutions, but ended up with no luck.

At this point i am testing app with **Android API 33.** once this start working then i need to do same testing with iphone device.

In Xamarin i was using nuget package  - **Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie.**

now in MAUI converted project, i installed nuget package - **SkiaSharp.Extended.UI.Maui**

This is a part of my code:

Step 1

In my code i am download and saving file to a custom folder.

> *Download and save process working fine.*

```
readonly string local_lottieJSON_folderName = "lottieJSON";

string ifolderPath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), local_lottieJSON_folderName));
```

XAML code: defaultAnim.json is located at RAW\json\defaultAnim.json.

> *This part is working fine.*

```
  <skia:SKLottieView
      x:Name="animation_view"
      Source="defaultAnim.json"
    RepeatCount="-1"
    HeightRequest="300"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

Step 2: C# Code side load file

> SKIA part has the issue

```
  //This is the path of Downloaded JSON file in varable "imagePath" "/data/user/0/com.companyname.xxxxxxxxxxxmaui/files/lottieJSON/animation_llhn6hu4.json"

 if (File.Exists(imagePath))
  {

      //OLD Airbnb.Xamari working code
      // get file full path and file name
      //string fileName = Path.Combine(imagePath);
      // read file
      //string json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
      //load the json animation
      //animation_view.SetAnimationFromJson(json);

      //NEW SKIA code for MAUI
      var a = new SKFileLottieImageSource();
      a.File = imagePath;   //// RAW folder working path "json\\iamhappy.json";
      animation_view.Source = a;

  }
```

> Extra info: i also tried these paths:
>
> "\data\user\0\com.companyname.xxxxxxxxxxxmaui\files\lottieJSON\animation_llhn6hu4.json"
>
> "/files/lottieJSON/animation_llhn6hu4.json"
>
> "files/lottieJSON/animation_llhn6hu4.json"
>
> "\files\lottieJSON\animation_llhn6hu4.json"
>
> "\lottieJSON\animation_llhn6hu4.json"
>
> "/lottieJSON/animation_llhn6hu4.json"
>
> I tested with Android emulator and a physical Samsung Android 13 device.

I found this example code as Jason suggested. no luck with result

```
            // Create a Stream that points to your Lottie animation file
            string folderPath = imagePath;
            string animationFileName = var_BundalID; // or the name of your Lottie animation file
            string animationFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, animationFileName);

            if (File.Exists(animationFilePath))
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(animationFilePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var skLottieImageSource = SKLottieImageSource.FromStream(stream);

                    // Now, you can use skLottieImageSource in your application
                    animation_view.Source = (SKLottieImageSource)skLottieImageSource;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle the case where the animation file does not exist
            }
```

UPDATE[9/15/2023]

Today i got little progress.

1st: i change variable type from **var** to **SKLottieImage**.

2nd: Then in VS debug mode, i have to put breakpoint after "animation_view.Source = skLottieImageSource;" and then hove over .source and then tree down to all the way to stream info value for animation_view.source. after that i press play in VS, then it load the json animation. no clue what is happening here now.

If i open all those popup box in debug mode , as shown in screenshot, then press play in VS, then json animation loads.
[image: Demo Img]

```
   using (var stream = new FileStream(filePathAndName, FileMode.Open))
     {
       //var skLottieImageSource = (SKLottieImageSource)SKLottieImageSource.FromStream(stream);
         SKLottieImageSource skLottieImageSource = (SKLottieImageSource)SKLottieImageSource.FromStream(stream);
    
         // Now, you can use skLottieImageSource in your application
         animation_view.Source = skLottieImageSource;
     }
```

OK i found an error with SKIA in output. if i do pull refresh page then it start througing out this error mutiple times.
@Jessie Zhang -MSFT

```
[skia] Shader compilation error
[skia] ------------------------
[skia]    1 #version 310 es
[skia]    2 
[skia]    3 precision mediump float;
[skia]    4 precision mediump sampler2D;
[skia]    5 const highp float PRECISION = 4.0;
[skia]    6 const highp float MAX_FIXED_RESOLVE_LEVEL = 5.0;
[skia]    7 const highp float MAX_FIXED_SEGMENTS = 32.0;
[skia]    8 uniform highp vec4 sk_RTAdjust;
[skia]    9 uniform highp vec4 uaffineMatrix_S0;
[skia]   10 uniform highp vec2 utranslate_S0;
[skia]   11 in highp vec2 resolveLevel_and_idx;
[skia]   12 in highp vec4 p01;
[skia]   13 in highp vec4 p23;
[skia]   14 in highp vec2 fanPointAttrib;
[skia]   15 highp float wangs_formula_max_fdiff_pow2_ff2f2f2f2f22(highp vec2 p0, highp vec2 p1, highp vec2 p2, highp vec2 p3, highp mat2 matrix) {
[skia]   16     highp vec2 d0 = matrix * (((vec2(-2.0)) * (p1) + (p2)) + p0);
[skia]   17     highp vec2 d1 = matrix * (((vec2(-2.0)) * (p2) + (p3)) + p1);
[skia]   18     return max(dot(d0, d0), dot(d1, d1));
[skia]   19 }
[skia]   20 highp float wangs_formula_conic_pow2_fff2f2f2f(highp float _precision_, highp vec2 p0, highp vec2 p1, highp vec2 p2, highp float w) {
[skia]   21     highp vec2 C = (min(min(p0, p1), p2) + max(max(p0, p1), p2)) * 0.5;
[skia]   22     p0 -= C;
[skia]   23     p1 -= C;
[skia]   24     p2 -= C;
[skia]   25     highp float m = sqrt(max(max(dot(p0, p0), dot(p1, p1)), dot(p2, p2)));
[skia]   26     highp vec2 dp = ((vec2(-2.0 * w)) * (p1) + (p0)) + p2;
[skia]   27     highp float dw = abs(((-2.0) * (w) + (2.0)));
[skia]   28     highp float rp_minus_1 = max(0.0, ((m) * (_precision_) + (-1.0)));
[skia]   29     highp float numer = length(dp) * _precision_ + rp_minus_1 * dw;
[skia]   30     highp float denom = 4.0 * min(w, 1.0);
[skia]   31     return numer / denom;
[skia]   32 }
[skia]   33 void main() {
[skia]   34     highp mat2 AFFINE_MATRIX = mat2(uaffineMatrix_S0);
[skia]   35     highp vec2 TRANSLATE = utranslate_S0;
[skia]   36     highp float resolveLevel = resolveLevel_and_idx.x;
[skia]   37     highp float idxInResolveLevel = resolveLevel_and_idx.y;
[skia]   38     highp vec2 localcoord;
[skia]   39     if (resolveLevel < 0.0) {
[skia]   40         localcoord = fanPointAttrib;
[skia]   41     } else {
[skia]   42         if (isinf(p23.z)) {
[skia]   43             localcoord = resolveLevel != 0.0 ? p01.zw : (idxInResolveLevel != 0.0 ? p23.xy : p01.xy);
[skia]   44         } else {
[skia]   45             highp vec2 p0 = p01.xy;
[skia]   46             highp vec2 p1 = p01.zw;
[skia]   47             highp vec2 p2 = p23.xy;
[skia]   48             highp vec2 p3 = p23.zw;
[skia]   49             highp float w = -1.0;
[skia]   50             highp float maxResolveLevel;
[skia]   51             if (isinf(p23.w)) {
[skia]   52                 w = p3.x;
[skia]   53                 highp float _0_n2 = wangs_formula_conic_pow2_fff2f2f2f(PRECISION, AFFINE_MATRIX * p0, AFFINE_MATRIX * p1, AFFINE_MATRIX * p2, w);
[skia]   54                 maxResolveLevel = ceil(log2(max(_0_n2, 1.0)) * 0.5);
[skia]   55                 p1 *= w;
[skia]   56                 p3 = p2;
[skia]   57             } else {
[skia]   58                 highp float _1_m = wangs_formula_max_fdiff_pow2_ff2f2f2f2f22(p0, p1, p2, p3, AFFINE_MATRIX);
[skia]   59                 maxResolveLevel = ceil(log2(max(9.0 * _1_m, 1.0)) * 0.25);
[skia]   60             }
[skia]   61             if (resolveLevel > maxResolveLevel) {
[skia]   62                 idxInResolveLevel = floor(ldexp(idxInResolveLevel, int(maxResolveLevel - resolveLevel)));
[skia]   63                 resolveLevel = maxResolveLevel;
[skia]   64             }
[skia]   65             highp float fixedVertexID = floor(0.5 + ldexp(idxInResolveLevel, int(MAX_FIXED_RESOLVE_LEVEL - resolveLevel)));
[skia]   66             if (0.0 < fixedVertexID && fixedVertexID < MAX_FIXED_SEGMENTS) {
[skia]   67                 highp float T = fixedVertexID * 0.03125;
[skia]   68                 highp vec2 ab = mix(p0, p1, T);
[skia]   69                 highp vec2 bc = mix(p1, p2, T);
[skia]   70                 highp vec2 cd = mix(p2, p3, T);
[skia]   71                 highp vec2 abc = mix(ab, bc, T);
[skia]   72                 highp vec2 bcd = mix(bc, cd, T);
[skia]   73                 highp vec2 abcd = mix(abc, bcd, T);
[skia]   74                 highp float u = mix(1.0, w, T);
[skia]   75                 highp float v = (w + 1.0) - u;
[skia]   76                 highp float uv = mix(u, v, T);
[skia]   77                 localcoord = w < 0.0 ? abcd : abc / uv;
[skia]   78             } else {
[skia]   79                 localcoord = fixedVertexID == 0.0 ? p0 : p3;
[skia]   80             }
[skia]   81         }
[skia]   82     }
[skia]   83     highp vec2 vertexpos = AFFINE_MATRIX * localcoord + TRANSLATE;
[skia]   84     gl_Position = vec4(vertexpos, 0.0, 1.0);
[skia]   85     gl_Position = vec4(gl_Position.xy * sk_RTAdjust.xz + gl_Position.ww * sk_RTAdjust.yw, 0.0, gl_Position.w);
[skia]   86 }
[skia]   87 
[skia] Errors:
[skia] Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
[skia] ERROR: 0:35: error(#53) Built-in function parameter type check fail: an operation which requires matrix parameters is used on a non matrix type!
[skia] ERROR: 0:35: error(#53) Built-in function parameter type check fail: an operation which requires matrix parameters is used on a non matrix type!
[skia] ERROR: error(#273) 2 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

Update [9/16/23]

Ok **found this workaround** to fix the issue with skia stream not loading.
after skia source load code need to wait/delay for minimum 5 seconds in my case.

```
using var stream = new FileStream(filePathAndName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

SKLottieImageSource skLottieImageSource = (SKLottieImageSource)SKLottieImageSource.FromStream(stream);

animation_view.Source = skLottieImageSource;

await PutTaskDelay(); // 




async Task PutTaskDelay()
 {
     //This is fix for skia delay.
     await Task.Delay(5000);
 }
```

I also tagged Xamarin community, because might someone from xamarin community made this work.

**Any advice or direction will be highly appreciable !!!**

Comment: Is there any log about this problem when you tried to use the code you posted above?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT, i added new update to my post. please see update UPDATE[9/15/2023]. thank you –

Comment: Congratulations on finding the solution.  Happy coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

open a `FileStream` and then use the static method

```
SKLottieImageSource.FromStream(...)
```

Comment: as you suggested, i found a small code and implemented in my project. but it not fix the issue. see my update in original post.